# getimagesize no longer works

Tags: php

My php/html application (on Centos 6.5) uses getimagesize() to enable scaling of images from the internet. It has stopped working and I don't know why. Allow url fopen is on.

For example:

```
$imginfo= getimagesize('http://www.chair.furniture/3592-large_default/eames-dsw-chair-.jpg');
```

Produces error:

```
PHP Warning:  getimagesize(http://www.chair.furniture/3592-large_default/eames-dsw-chair-.jpg): failed to open stream: Connection timed out in ....
```

This doesn't work with any urls. It hangs for about 60 seconds and then returns false.

I have also tried:

```
$image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($url));
```

But this produces a similar error:

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://www.chair.furniture/3592-large_default/eames-dsw-chair-.jpg): failed to open stream: Connection timed out in....
```

Firewall settings:

```
**INPUT**
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:443 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
**OUTPUT**
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:80 state ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:443 state ESTABLISHED
```

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: that is not getimagesize's problem. something is blocking PHP from doing external http connections - e.g. a firewall or something.

Comment: @MarcB I have included my firewall settings above. Perhaps I am missing state NEW for OUTPUT on ports 80, 443?

Comment: Do you have 'allow_url_fopen' PHP option enabled? Check your PHP settings.

Comment: @YasenZhelev yes sir! (as mentioned above ;-)

Comment: Yes, you are right. All I can think of despite of what was already said are DNS issues.

Comment: Do you have *explicit* permission from the remote site to scrape their images? Because if you don't then they've probably blocked you.

Comment: what about upstream firewalls? your server may be wide open, but the ISP may be doing something at the switch/router level. It wouldn't be a DNS issue. that'd be "unable to resolve host" or whatever. timed out = tcp connection was attempted, but didn't get established or was closed without ever receiving anything.

Comment: @Sammitch no I don't. My site (not yet live) is for users to include images themselves so it is up to them. However I have found that getimagesize does not seem to work from any site. They can't all have 'blocked me'. NB how would they do that anyway?